# present simple + present perfect/ past simple

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I made an exam 2 months ago, and now I am saying:

"I think that I have suceeded the exam or I think I succeed the exam"
According to me, the PP is better because the past action is relevant in the present.

It is that?

Comment: You _take_ or _sit_ an exam, and if you are successful you _pass_ it. If you haven't had the result yet, you might say "I think/hope I have passed."

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, yes, so we use the PP when the action is past but in the present there is someting as if it was an ongoing action, the action is not finished.

Comment: "relevant in the present" is not really a good rule for when to use the Present Perfect.  Remember that the PP is actually a *present* tense, so it's used to describe your current status!  But passing the exam was a single event in the past, not a present event.

Comment: @stangdon so according to you, past simple here is better?

Comment: @Meedfried14 Yes, I would just say "I think I passed."

Comment: @stangdon - This is where we come up against the 'divided by a common language' thing. Most Brits would say "I think I've passed."